# .NET SOAP web service serialization error

Tags: .net, soap, asmx

I want to create universal class (with object type parameter) for sending object to SOAP web service.

```
   public class ReturnObject
   {
       public int ReturnCode;
       public object ReturnValue;

       public ReturnObject() { }

       public ReturnObject(int resultCode, object resultValue)
       {
           this.ReturnCode = resultCode;
           this.ReturnValue = resultValue;
       }
   }
```

But I receive serialization error.

Can anyone suggest me, where I'm wrong?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: First, how are you expose your web service?  Is it WCF or through some other means (traditional ASP.NET web services)?  Also, you should show the details of the error, "serialization error" is quite broad.

Comment: I use traditional ASP.NET web services

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that ReturnValue is some type that the SOAP serializer doesn't support.

Sure would be nice to at least see the error though...